# Dynamic ShuttleBox implementation using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am looking out for some piece of javascript which can implement ShuttleBox kind of functionality.

Basically I need to provide 2 list box and 4 buttons - Move Left, Move Right, Move All to Left and Move All to Right. But I want to implement this piece of code dynamic so that it can be reused by just passing dom object in the parameters only...

Any piece of code or link, would be highly appreciated...

Thanks...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filterable multi-select combobox shuttle/transfer widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366940/filterable-multi-select-combobox-shuttle-transfer-widget)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like that?:

```
<html>
<body>

<script>
function move_right()
{
    var node = document.getElementById ( "left" );
    for (i=0; i < node.childNodes.length; i ++)
    {
        if ( node.childNodes[i].selected )
        {
            document.getElementById ( "right" ).appendChild( node.childNodes[i].cloneNode(true) );
            node.removeChild ( node.childNodes[i] );
            -- i;
        }
    }
}

function move_left()
{
    var node = document.getElementById ( "right" );
    for (i=0; i < node.childNodes.length; i ++)
    {
        if ( node.childNodes[i].selected )
        {
            document.getElementById ( "left" ).appendChild( node.childNodes[i].cloneNode(true) );
            node.removeChild ( node.childNodes[i] );
            -- i;
        }
    }
}

function move_all_right()
{
    var node = document.getElementById ( "left" );      
    while ( node.childNodes.length > 0 )        
    {           
        document.getElementById ( "right" ).appendChild( node.firstChild.cloneNode(true) );
        node.removeChild ( node.firstChild );           
    }       
}

function move_all_left()
{
    var node = document.getElementById ( "right" );     
    while ( node.childNodes.length > 0 )        
    {           
        document.getElementById ( "left" ).appendChild( node.firstChild.cloneNode(true) );
        node.removeChild ( node.firstChild );           
    }       
}
</script>
<select multiple="multiple" id="left"><option>item 0</option><option>item 1</option><option>item 2</option><option>item 3</option></select>
<input type="button" value="<" onclick="move_left()"/>
<input type="button" value="<<" onclick="move_all_left()"/>
<input type="button" value=">>" onclick="move_all_right()"/>
<input type="button" value=">" onclick="move_right()"/>
<select multiple="multiple" id="right"></select>

</body>
</html>
```