# Implement multi-item selector in Spring 3 and JSP

Tags: jquery, spring, jsp

I would like to implement in Spring 3 and JSP a UI form like the following (easily implemented with Java Swing):

[image]

Googling around I've found similar things, but not a complete example that could save me some development time.
Does anybody have a quick full tutorial or link to it? The idea is to make it work dynamically, so I guess this should include some jQuery.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the pattern for things like this is

- wire up your controller and JSP with standard HTML inputs using appropriate JSP tags for your framework
- layer jQuery UI on top of the existing HTML

For this specific example, see: [Filterable multi-select combobox shuttle/transfer widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366940/filterable-multi-select-combobox-shuttle-transfer-widget)

for ideas on how to do it on the client side.  You would include the client side code in your JSP with JS and jQuery.

On the server-side, it would just look like another `<select>` that is part of your Model that you process within your `@Controller` method.

It's a similar pattern for things like sliders (look like regular text input).