# Input 'less than, greater than, equals to' software versions in a HTML form?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, html, range

I have a HTML form which allows the input of software versions (for example 1.1.1, 1.0, etc). Specifically WordPress software versions. Currently each version has its own text input box. When a lot of versions are needed the HTML form looks a mess and it takes a lot of time to input them all.

I am looking for a solution which would allow me to use greater than (>), less than (<) and equals to (=) logic to input the WordPress software versions.

For example:

I have these software versions: 1.0, 1.2, 1.3, 2.0

- The user inputs: "< 1.2" - the form would submit: "1.0"
- The user inputs: "<= 1.3" - the form would submit: "1.0,1.2,1.3"
- The user inputs: "> 1.3" - the form would submit: "2.0"

[HTML5's Range](http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-range.php) input does not seem adequate as it only allows for 1 value.

[Jquery UI's Range Slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range) may be a suitable option.

Is there anything out there designed for this kind of software version input?

I'm working with Rails on the backend if that matters.

Comment: So there is never a case where a user would want to submit 1.0 and 1.3 but not 1.2?

Comment: Out of curiosity, where are your version numbers coming from? I ask because version numbers are notoriously hard to parse. For example, does `2.11` come after `2.1` or `2.10`? If the software uses [Semver](http://semver.org/), however, you're in much better shape, and there are some [great libraries for that](https://github.com/npm/node-semver).

Comment: Digital Chris - Rarely but possible.

Comment: Jordan - they are WordPress release software versions, I'll update my question with that information. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I assume you know all the proper versions for each software piece you're presenting.  If that's the case, why require the users to input it themselves instead of printing down all the options as, say, a multi select, or a set of checkboxes or the like?  Such controls would give them greater control over their submissions as well as prevent potential fatfingering.

Comment: @JDS that is just what I was thinking. Or a [multi select shuttle/transfer like the one described in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366940/filterable-multi-select-combobox-shuttle-transfer-widget).

Comment: JDS, @Digital Chris - I'm thinking this might work is parsed properly on the server? http://jsfiddle.net/n54srxxt/1/

Comment: Why do you expect (and require?) the user to type e.g. `> 1.3`? Isn’t it much more natural that he enters an actual version number? You form handling code should then take it from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize Rubygems version support for this. The will work on the backend, not client side, but you can make an ajax request to parse and return the satisfied versions.

First, create an array of Gem::Version for each version you want to match against the user entered requirement:

```
require 'rubygems'
versions = %w(1.0 1.2 1.3 2.0).map { |s| Gem::Version.new(s) }
requirement = Gem::Requirement.new("<= 1.3")
```

Now you can find all versions that satisfy the requirement:

```
satisfied_versions = versions.select { |v| req.satisfied_by?(v) }
# => [#<Gem::Version "1.3">, #<Gem::Version "1.2">, #<Gem::Version "1.0">]
```

If you want just the version strings:

```
satisfied_versions.map { |v| v.to_s }
# => ["1.3", "1.2", "1.0"]
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks great. For the view I might use something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/n54srxxt/1/